# unable to insert and retrive mysql server database information

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

i have created a database named test(table name demo) on wamp on my friend's pc.i am able to see this table from my browser using ip address of my friend's pc. but i want to insert and retrive data into this database(test) using java code from my pc. i try that but netbeans shows an error message.

```
here is my code :


package ashdemo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Ashdemo {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://friend's_ipaddress:3306/test","username","password



"); 
                    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                  stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into demo values(1,'abc','nagpur')");
                    //ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("Select name from demo where id=1");
                    //rs.next();
                   //String name= rs.getString("name");               
                    //System.out.println(name);
                    System.out.println("DOne..");
                   //INSERT INTO `student`(`id`, `name`, `address`) VALUES (1,'amol','nagpur');
                con.close();

              }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        System.out.println("error"+e);
    }

    }

    }
error message is :
```

> errorjava.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   'username'@'myipaddress' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up mysql to **allow remote connection for a particular user**. The default syntax is:

`grant <permission> on <database> to <user>@<location> identified by <password>`

So here you have to use-

`grant all on test.* to 'username'@'your_ipaddress' identified by 'password'`

Run this command in MySQL command prompt.

This will allow **username** to **connect from your IP** using that **password** and give all permissions on all tables in the database-`test`.

- To allow **any user** to connect **from any IP address** and use **all the tables in any database** use the following syntax-

`grant all on *.* to '%'@'%' identified by 'password'`

And finally you have to use the following command-

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

To reload all privileges.

Comment: thanks.. it did the work for me.
i dont have words to thank you.