# how to connect online mysql database server from local wamp server using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to connect my online mysql database from local wamp/xampp server using php

I need to update some table in my online phpmyadmin database from my local phpmyadmin  database , It is possible ?
my local machine have internet connection ,

Comment: Are you using `cPanel` ?

Comment: `my online phpmyadmin database` - if you're using phpmyadmin on the server anyway - why not _just_ use phpmyadmin on the server ..? What's the purpose of what you're asking?

Comment: Yes , I am using cpanel , i need to update my local database table to my current online cpanel phpMyadmin database, how i connect the another online PhpMyadmin database and local machine Php Myadmin database

Did you have any php scripts for this solution ?

Answer (score 2):

To connect to remote server from your local machine you need some already granted `privileges` on that server itself with your **IP** and an **username** with a prespecified **password**. So you can't do it without their permission.

Check this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19231880/2758467)**

After that you are allowed to create connection to that remote database server using the following syntax:

```
$hostname='www.facebook.com';// Remote database server Domain name.
$username='username';// as specified in the GRANT command at that server.
$password='password';// as specified in the GRANT command at that server.
$dbname='testdb';// Database name at the database server.
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: I need to connect  Mysql Database using php ,

Comment: If i am putting permission to my online PHP Database its showing error message

Answer (score 1):

If your database is on a Shared Server Hosting. Some hosting providers does not allow you to connect to your databases remotely.

Here's a quick [`walkthrough`](http://kb.liquidweb.com/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/) of how to do a remote connection to your database.

Comment: Thank you , Have any more idea to slove my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading SQLYog (Community edition).

http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list

It's good for this sort of thing, if you can get to the remote host on standard mysql port 3306. If you're going to connect from php on your local machine, you'll probably go through the same port using one of the php libraries to the remote machine with one connection, and to your local database with with another connection. The tool will let you verify and test the connections and test the queries interactively.

Comment: This does not seem to be an appropriate answer - the author needs to change/verify connection credentials  in his local machine (i.e. that's the problem/question) and instead you've proposed to use a (not free) different tool which will have exactly the same question/problem.

Comment: The Community Edition is free. One way or another, he needs to test the connections, and view the configuration settings and tables. The question seems to be how to connect to both. I don't think phpmadmin supports multiple simultaneous connections. Or even sequential connections with much ease. Of course he still has to do the work himself. It's just a tool that lets you compare and copy from one to another.